# Is there any other way to push large pickle files (bigger than 100 MB) to GitHub repo other than Git LFS? (For my ML project)

Tags: python, github, machine-learning, pickle, streamlit

I am a beginner in ML. As per my understanding, we generally store our trained model in a pickle file. (If we are working in Python). However, GitHub has a file size upload limit of 100 MB. For files having size more than 100 MB, developers generally use Git LFS. However, Git LFS has limited free-tier usage. Is there any other way to push large pickle files (bigger than 100 MB) to GitHub repo without using Git LFS?

I used Git LFS for my project and it worked fine for a few days. However, I ran out of my free-tier usage and now my project app (hosted on Streamlit Cloud) is not working anymore. I tried Googling some other solutions, but to no avail. How do I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Under our assumption that we can always retrain, we store our trained models on s3 or one of the other cloud providers.

Comment: You might want to look into a tool like DVC: https://dvc.org/

It allows you to use git to store _information_ about your data and your model, but actually _host_ these things elsewhere, like Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage, Google Drive, or a bunch of other places.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub doesn't allow files to be larger than 100 MB except for Git LFS files.  For existing projects with a large history containing a handful of offending files (e.g., forks of Chromium), a temporary exception can sometimes be made by Support, provided that you're not planning to add more such files.  That's because very large files pack poorly and cause timeouts when GitHub is maintaining the repo.

As a side note, pickle files are not a good idea to share.  Loading an untrusted pickle file can execute arbitrary code on your system, and thus are not a secure method of interchange.